# How to set chromium to open word documents with libreoffice?

Tags: 12.10, lubuntu, chromium, gmail

When I click on a word attachment in an email I have received in gmail from chromium, it always opens the file using abiword. How can I persuade it to use libreoffice instead?  I am using lubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Chromium* uses `xdg-open` to open the application for a file type. So, all you need to do is adjust your `xdg` configuration, or in other words change the default application that handles a particular file type.

To associate a particular application to a file type or *Mime Type* (MIME stands for Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions), we make an entry in `~/.local/usr/share/applications/mimeapps.list` stating that a particular application to be opened when a file with the correspoding mime type is opened.

*I've provided sources below, in case you want to know more about mime types*

In this case, do the following:

- Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>).
- Run the following command to make an entry:

```
xdg-mime default libreoffice-writer.desktop application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-template application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-web application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-master application/vnd.sun.xml.writer application/vnd.sun.xml.writer.template application/vnd.sun.xml.writer.global application/msword application/vnd.ms-word application/x-doc application/x-hwp application/rtf text/rtf application/vnd.wordperfect application/wordperfect application/vnd.lotus-wordpro application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroenabled.12 application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroenabled.12 application/vnd.ms-works application/vnd.stardivision.writer-global application/x-extension-txt application/x-t602 text/plain
```

In case, you've Libreoffice 4 installed, run:

```
xdg-mime default libreoffice4.0-writer.desktop application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-template application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-web application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text-master application/vnd.sun.xml.writer application/vnd.sun.xml.writer.template application/vnd.sun.xml.writer.global application/msword application/vnd.ms-word application/x-doc application/x-hwp application/rtf text/rtf application/vnd.wordperfect application/wordperfect application/vnd.lotus-wordpro application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroenabled.12 application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroenabled.12 application/vnd.ms-works application/vnd.stardivision.writer-global application/x-extension-txt application/x-t602 text/plain
```

- You might need to logout and login again for the changes to take effect.

**Further information & Sources:**

- http://www.packtpub.com/article/control-of-file-types-in-ubuntu
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type
- http://www.libre-software.net/change-the-default-application-ubuntu-linux
- http://blog.radevic.com/2012/02/how-to-set-default-apps-aka-how-to-use.html

Comment: That's great, thanks.  Is this long command line really the recommended way to change application preferences for chromium?

Comment: You can choose which file type to open, for example if you only want to open MS Word files to open using Libreoffice Writer, you can write `xdg-mime default libreoffice-writer.desktop application/msword`